# Is the number of static variables limited in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was talking with developpers from a platform which are claiming to support C++, but they said, in the same breath, that the number of static variables that are cleand-up at programm exit is bound to a magic number (i think they said 32 on their platform), they say that is conform with the C++ standard.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not correct at all.

Comment: I hope the compiler at least warns about this

Comment: Implementations always have limitations.  For example on the depth of template recursion, the length of identifiers, or the maximum number of lines in a translation unit able to be debugged (Solaris was 65536 for a long time).

Comment: did you ask the developer if he could point out the section from the standard where that was stated?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Mostly lazyness on their side. Don't forget that they may need to run far more than 32 dtors, when those static variables have members that also have dtors.

Comment: Just for our curiosity (mine, at least), what is the platform and compiler referenced here?

Comment: This is precisely why Annex B ("Implementation Quantities") exists in the standard. It allows implementations to set limits like this, as long as they're properly documented. So if this implementation documents a limit on the amount of static objects, then that's perfectly fine with the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard says that all destructors *must* be called if they have side effects.

> `[basic.start.term]/1:` Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects (that is, objects whose lifetime (3.8) has begun) with static storage
>   duration are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling std::exit (18.5). [...]
>
> `[basic.stc.static]/2:` If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be
>   eliminated even if it appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated
>   as specified in 12.8.
>   The keyword static can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration.

However, the rules on standards compliance do allow for some leeway when it comes to implementation limits:

> `[intro.compilance]/2.1:` If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, **within its resource limits**, accept and correctly execute that program.

A hard limit on the number of static variables allowed may seem odd, but common implementations have hard limits on all sorts of things, e.g. template instantiation depth.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a limit in the static variables cleaned-up at program exit, it surely is NOT mandated by the C++ language standard.

Depending on the platform, compiler and runtime library, there may be however be some limitation, i.e. on embedded platforms with small CPU capabilities and/or strict memory constraints.

Comment: But they do not conform with the standard, if i get you right

Comment: The standard allows for some freedom on implementation, IF it is compliant AND does not violate other rules. See TartanLlama answer for references.

Comment: I would phrase it as "the standard does not *require* a limit on the number of static variables that have destructors - but it does *permit* such a limit.